# Shapely STRtree way too slow?

Tags: python, shapely, spatial-index

I need to map several hundred thousand nodes to their nearest neighbors in as set of a few ten thousand other nodes. Naturally, I would use a spatial index to speed up this process. I was previously able to this very quickly by generating a Voronoi tessellation of the smaller node set and using MySQL spatial queries to determine which nodes in the first set fell in the region associated with the node of the second set. This was able to run in just a few minutes. I have since moved away from a MySQL environment and wanted to do the entire process in python. I turned towards the popular STRtree spatial index provided by the shapely package. However, I found that this index is incredibly slow. I tried using both the nearest geometry query with sets of nodes as well as the geometry intersection query with Voronoi regions and only got as fast as 51.787 matched nodes per a second, which would take about 4.5 hours to run each set of nodes I handle. Why is shapely so slow? Or am I using it incorrectly?

Some code snippets:

```py
class Network:

    ...

    def load_network(self, planspath):
        log.info('Fetching temperatures.')
        temperatures = self.fetch_temperatures()
        log.info('Fetching centroids.')
        centroids = self.fetch_centroids()
        log.info('Fetching links.')
        links = self.fetch_links()

        Centroid.steps = len(next(iter(temperatures.values())))

        log.info('Building spatial index (strtree) from centroids.')
        points = []
        for centroid in centroids.values():
            uuid = centroid[0]
            self.centroids[uuid] = Centroid(temperatures[centroid[1]])
            point = loads(centroid[2])
            setattr(point, 'id', uuid)
            points.append(point)
        tree = STRtree(points)

        log.info('Mapping links to centroids.')
        for link in links:
            node = loads(link[4])
            point = tree.nearest(node)
            self.links[link[0]] = Link(link[1], link[2], self.centroids[point.id])

        log.info('Loading network routes from output plans file.')
        self.routes = self.fetch_routes(planspath)
```

Comment: Please post text results of A) SELECT @@version; and B) SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name for each table with spatial datatypes and C) how are you connecting to MySQL? and D) how much RAM and core count on the server?

Answer (score 1):

The poor performance was the result of a bug in Shapely. A fix has been committed and will be available in the next version.